# Bad looking highlighted text in windows forms + changing focus on click

Tags: c#, windows, windows-forms-designer

At the start - i'm starting with windows forms/making desktop applications.

So, I'm moving my program from javascript to c# - desktop app, with full user interface and etc. and I have 2 questions:

1. I added textbox, and checkbox, it looks good until I highlight the text or it also looks good only if the background behind the app is white in every other case it looks like that, here the image : [image: Highlighted text on black background]

How can i fix that?

2nd question:
I had the issue with the texboxes - the borders were invisible and when i clicked them windows was focusing on the app behind my program. I fixed it with changing border from "fixed3D" to "fixedSingle", I also had the same issue with the listbox (under the texboxes) also changed the border to "fixedSingle", but it's loosing now focus when i click the text inside this.  How can i solve that? + maybe make the program to not hightlight the text on click in listbox? - it looks better without it

Comment: WinForms is not a good choice for _aesthetic_ applications - is there a reason you're not using WPF/XAML/UWP instead?

Comment: @Dai im learning, so i wrote how to make windows app in c# and there was a lot of things about the windows forms. That's why i've chosen that